# Failed to run com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.AidlProcessor

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, aidl

I got a project from a developer which is already completed and working fine for him on his computer. When I try to build that project on my computer in eclipse, then I am getting following error message:

Failed to run com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.AidlProcessor.

Developer is using AIDL files into the project and I think my eclipse is not able to run those file... I searched lot about this on internet but did not get any help.

Please let me if someone have any idea about this problem.

Thanks,

Wave

Comment: I'm seeing this too. According to workspace/.metadata/.log, AidlProcessor is crashing with NullPointerException in AidlProcessor.doCompileFiles(AidlProcessor.java:113)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will help in your case, but in mine, I deleted the project, deleted the .classpath file, and then went through the "new android project from existing source" workflow again.  I don't know what was wrong with the original .classpath, but that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you haven't installed Android SDK and Android ADT for Eclipse or you install them improperly? Try to reinstall them.

This problem is very unusual and some unusual problems happen if you use JDK 7. For Android development you should use JDK 6. Check this also! Good luck!

Comment: I have Android SDK and Android ADT installed and these are working fine for my other Android projects. Working other projects fine also prove that I am using JDK6. I am having problem in running projects with AIDL files... May b something is missing in my Android ADT, but I am not able to find that...Anyway I appreciate that you replied and helped me.

Comment: Try to check if you have downloaded aidl.exe. It's in android-sdk/platform-tools

Comment: Even i am facing same issue, every thing is in place. Kindly help

Comment: I can only advice you reinstall your Eclipse and Android SDK. Sometimes this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of them:

1. Change your workspace.
2. Delete   **com.android.ide.eclipse.adt** folder from your **metadata**. **plugins** \
3. Add **exported="true"** to the **classpathentry** in your **.classpath**

Answer (score 0):

I had error in importing project.I deleted .classpath file and then imported and it worked.