# Unable to run the Android project in Eclipse: .aidl error

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, nullpointerexception, aidl

I am trying to run a particular Android project in Eclipse 4.2.1(Juno). And it is giving following error when I try to compile it.

```
Failed to run com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.AidlProcessor. Check workspace log for detail.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.AidlProcessor.doCompileFiles(AidlProcessor.java:116)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.SourceProcessor.compileFiles(SourceProcessor.java:245)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.build(PreCompilerBuilder.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I haven't used any aidl file in my project.

I have installed latest SDK and latest ADT.

NOTE: I am able to run other projects perfectly fine in this Eclipse, except this one. 
I have also checked following links without any success:

[Failed to run com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.AidlProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11690543/480346)

[AIDL files not building in Eclipse in random projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10261781/480346)

Can you please let us know what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check the workspace log, as the error message suggests?  What did it say?

Comment: I have pasted the workspace log in my question.

Comment: that isn't the workspace log: that is the logcat.  Look at the ErrorLog view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this by creating a new project and copied all files in it. Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your eclipse C:\path\to\eclipse\eclipse -clean

Comment: Yes, did that. Still same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

It worked out for me hope it works for you as well.

1. Delete the project from eclipse, go to your project directory, delete .settings and .classpath.
2. Refresh the directory and import the project again in the eclipse.